# Modify beforeskip for unnumbered chapters in scrbook

Tags: spacing, sectioning, koma-script, scrbook

I would like to adjust the vertical spacing before unnumbered chapters *only*. I like the default for numbered chapters, but I need a single page abstract, and the big vertical skip takes up too much space. I tried something like:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter{}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt]{addchap}
\addchap{Abstract}
Hello, world!

\mainmatter{}
\chapter{Introduction}
Goodbye!

\end{document}
```

... but `\addchap` cannot be independently modified. I see two logical workarounds:

1. Create something like `frontchap` to be a perfect copy of `\chapter` but with no `beforeskip` and no number.
2. Use `\RedeclareSectionCommand` at the beginning of frontmatter to change the `beforeskip` of `\chapter`, and at the beginning of mainmatter to go back to default.

But I am not 100% sure how would I implement either. Is there a KOMA command for 'create sectioning command based on existing one'? Or 'go back to defaults'? I would rather avoid hardcoding a specific beforeskip value and use the one calculated based on current font size etc.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=1sp]{chapter}`? I think you were on the right track, just `0pt` wouldn't work. Or, if this is a single instance in your document, just add a negative `\vspace` yourself as a one-time solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `\frontmatter\renewcommand*\chapterheadstartvskip{}` to remove the vertical space before chapter titles in front matter and `\mainmatter\KOMAoptions{headings=big}` to restore the default settings.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\renewcommand*\chapterheadstartvskip{}% removes space before chapter titles 
\chapter{Abstract}
Hello, world!

\mainmatter
\KOMAoptions{headings=big}% restores default space before chapter titles
\chapter{Introduction}
Goodbye!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that chapters in front matter are unnumbered by default.

---

You can also define a new sectioning command `\frontchap`:

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}[2020/01/24]
\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level:=chapter,
  indent:=chapter,
  numwidth:=chapter,
  beforeskip:=chapter
]{chapter}{frontchap}
\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
  style=chapter,
  level=\chapternumdepth,
  beforeskip=0pt,
  afterindent=false
]{frontchap}

\BeforeTOCHead{\let\chapter\frontchap}
\let\frontchapmark\chaptermark
\let\frontchapmarkformat\chaptermarkformat
\makeatletter
\let\c@frontchap\c@chapter% use the same counter
\def\cl@frontchap{\cl@chapter}% use the same reset list
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\frontchap{Abstract}
Hello, world!
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
Goodbye!
\end{document}
```